# SAX parse <xsd:appinfo> tag

Tags: xml, xsd, sax

Is it possible to read the value stored in `<xsd:appinfo>` tag in a given XML through SAX. Currently I am using a custom implementation of DefaultHandler class to read the elements and the values in the XML. I now need to read additional information stored in the `<xsd:appinfo>` tag.

I am trying to validate a XML against a XSD schema. I have used SAX to validate the schema using the code below

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(false);
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
                .newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        SAXParser parser = null;
        try {
            factory.setSchema(schemaFactory
                    .newSchema(new Source[] { new StreamSource(xsd) }));
            parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        } catch (SAXException se) {
            System.out.println("SCHEMA : " + se.getMessage()); // problem in
                                                                // the XSD
                                                                // itself
            isInvalid=true;
        }

        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        final MyContentHandler xpathTracker = new MyContentHandler();

        reader.setContentHandler(xpathTracker);
        reader.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
            public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println("WARNING: " + e.getMessage());
                                      // do nothing
            }

            public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {                    
                xpathError.add(xpathTracker.getXPath());
            }
```

I have the following code for the ContentHandler

```
public class MyContentHandler extends XMLFilterImpl {

private final Stack<StackElement> stackElements = new Stack<StackElement>();

public MyContentHandler() {
    super();
}

public MyContentHandler(XMLReader parent) {
    super(parent);
}

public MyContentHandler(ContentHandler contentHandler) {
    setContentHandler(contentHandler);
}

public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    super.startDocument();
    stackElements.clear();   
    stackElements.push(new StackElement());
}

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts); 
    //add new element to stack
     stackElements.push(new StackElement());        
     stackElements.peek().update(uri,localName,qName);

}


public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
    stackElements.pop();
}

public String getCurrentElement(){
     return stackElements.peek().getCurrent();
}

/**
 * Gets the XPath to the current element.
 */
public String getXPath() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (StackElement h : stackElements) {
        h.appendPath(buf);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

}

The idea is that if the XSD validation fails for any element, I need to report back the full XPATH of the element. The code above along with the DefaultHandler does that. Now my requirement is that in addition to reporting the XPATH it should also print out a error code which is provided as part of the `<xsd:appinfo>`. A snippet of the XSD is below.

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="seqid" type="nonEmptyString">
        <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>ERROR_CODE="ERR_123</xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. But you need to include your code otherwise this question will be closed. Please edit your question, describe what you want to achieve and add the code you are talking about. Use the formatting tools, markdown and the (`{}`) button to format your code.